# NodeJs + Express - Setting static directory dynamically inside app.get()

Tags: node.js, express

I know the way to set the static directory like so:

```
app.use("/sandbox", express.static(__dirname + '/' + req.params.id+ '/' + siteDir));
```

BUT, I want the static directory to be set dynamically inside app.get() for each request individually.

What is the way to do that correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options to handle this. The first could be to use a wildcard route. But that is considered an anti-pattern.

You could also use **app parameters** in any request

```
app.get('/users/:userId/books/:bookId', function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.params)
})

// Route path: /users/:userId/books/:bookId
// Request URL: http://localhost:3000/users/34/books/8989
// req.params: { "userId": "34", "bookId": "8989" }
```

Another option is using regex in your get routes

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't see how it's related to the question. I need to set the static directory for assets like css, images and js files. But i need to set it inside the route for each request dynamically.

Comment: Each route can send static resources from a different directory. Please elaborate on the question so a better answer can be provided.